# Dynamic change of chartplot size for Highcharts

Tags: jquery, size, alignment, highcharts

i have a problem with the size of my charts made with Highcharts.
For better understanding I attached a screenshot of the current situation.
I want that all pies are actually the same size and they should be horizontal aligned. Since the values are dynamic I can't just set the heights of the chart container by trial&error to the correct size.

Here is the code of one chart and the relating container:

```
var auftrag;
$(document).ready(function() {
    auftrag = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'angebot-container',
            height: 400,
            plotBackgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
            backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, ',', '.') +' €';

            },
            positioner: function () {
                return { x: 3, y: 40 };
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: '',
            data: [
                <?php
                foreach ($offerPie as $offer) {
                    echo '[\'' . utf8_encode(shorten_word($offer['company'], 20, '...')) . '\', ' . $offer['summe'] . '],';
                }
                ?>
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

and here is the markup for the container:

```
<div class="chart" id="angebot-container" style="min-width: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I tried several things, but I didn't even came close to what I want.
The problem is, that the Items in the legend can change and the height of the legend changes the height and width of the actual pie.

[image: This is what it currently looks like]

Answer (score 0):

How about move your legend ?

```
...
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 100
},
...
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CqJkr/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what i am looking for. I dont have the space to align the legend left or right.